# No Bootstrap CSS in Bower install

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I installed Bootstrap using `bower install bootstrap` (it installed 3.1.1, apparently) but the `dist/css/bootstrap.css` file doesn't contain any Bootstrap styles, only normalize.css, which is a dependency of Bootstrap?

I understand I can just put download the CSS and put it somewhere in my project but I'd prefer to use Bower. Am I missing a step or is there a problem with the version of Bootstrap I've downloaded?

Comment: just tried the same thing and I got the entire package no problem. bootstrap.css starts off with a normalize but then continues to have all the rest of the bootstrap goodness... The only thing I can say is delete the directory in bower_components and try again. It works...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was attempting to use styles that were removed or something. They were not in the file and I thought that meant something was wrong on Bootstrap's end.

Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a trivial bug of the Bootstrap version 3.3.5. To fix this, I manually add the "dist/css/bootstrap.css" to the bower.json under the bootstrap folder and it works well. Remember to add it to the "main" section. Cheers.